# A question about CPFP relaying policy

Tags: mempool, replace-by-fee, child-pays-for-parent, package-relay

Let's say I broadcast a transaction `tx0` signaling RBF replaceability. Later on, send another transaction `tx1` that spends the same inputs of `tx0`, but this time with higher fees.

In this case, tx0 is **removed** from mempool right? so what if then I try to send a child transaction `tx0child` that forms a more profitable CPFP than `tx1` alone? But without the context of **removed** parent (`tx0`) this CPFP cannot work then, although it's more profitable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Correct. `tx0` is removed, and `tx0child` is "invalid" because it spends a UTXO that does not exist in the current chain or mempool. This could change in the future with package RBF and package relay if `tx0 + tx0child` are submitted as a package.

In this scenario, if the goal for `tx0child` was to fee-bump the original payment and RBF is possible, it probably makes more sense to just create another RBF to replace `tx1`.